# Origem da gíria "tá de rosca"

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem

O [significado](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/t%E1+de+rosca/) desta gíria (português brasileiro, não sei se é usado em Portugal):

> Não funciona, não dá certo.

ou

> Denominação dada a algo que estar muito demorada, difícil de realizar.

Pesquisando rapidamente não achei nada relevante sobre a origem. E parando pra pensar não tenho muita ideia se a rosca tem relação com algo vulgar ou só a rosca do parafuso mesmo que está interminável.

Qual a origem?

EDIT:
Ouço aqui em São Paulo, porém aparentemente a gíria foi [importada do Nordeste](https://viagemclub.com.br/girias-nordestinas/) do Brasil em específico de Pernambuco.

Comment: De que região é essa gíria? Nunca ouvi falar...

Comment: @FelipeChavesdeOliveira ouço em São Paulo, não sei da onde é predominantemente.

Comment: Eu sou de Curitiba, e ja fui a São Paulo inúmeras vezes, mas nunca ouvi. Interessante!

Comment: Talvez queira dizer que a pessoa esteja... dando o **parafuso**, então está demorando. Esta ação ser usada para expressada demora já ouvi, tipo "'tá demorando por quê? 'tá fazendo transação de crédito consignado?" só que mais... expressivo. Vendo o Priberam, pode ser que a pessoa esteja bêbada ou, como disse, tipo rosca que não sai, pensando na rosca que têm algumas bebidas.